# function of に in 学業にスポーツ

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-に

学業にスポーツ、なにをやっても秀でいる兄と違い、原島は、何もかもが平凡であった。
I can`t figure out the meaning/funtction of に in this sentence...
I checked a page which listed several usages of [に](http://www.coelang.tufs.ac.jp/mt/ja/gmod/contents/explanation/053.html) but nothing seems to fit

Answer (score 1):

It means "**and; in addition to**". In case you need some source, check [here](https://dict.asia/jc/%E3%81%AB) or [here](https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%AB).

> そのものに、さらに何かを添える意を表す。

You might have heard of 「それに」, meaning 「そのうえ。それに加えて」, example sentences:

> 晴れたし、それに風もない。
>
> この料理まずいし、それに高い。

And you can find the usage in [「ドラえもんのうた」](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vh3ZFtVqzac)

> 宿題(しゅくだい)　当番(とうばん)　試験(しけん)**に**　おつかい
>
> あんなこと　こんなこと　たいへんだけど

宿題　当番　試験**に**　おつかい means 宿題+当番+試験+(**に**)おつかい

In you sentence, 「学業にスポーツ」 means 「学業」 plus 「スポーツ」, both the two.